# Testing Symfony flex on Windows

Tags: php, composer-php, symfony4

I can't make composer working with flex receipe on a symfony4 project, on Windows.

Here is the complete process :

- I installed PHP7.2 from http://windows.php.net/download#php-7.2 (VC15 x86 Non Thread Safe), PATH env is set. php.ini is created (from php.ini-development). PHP is working on windows (`php -v`).
- I installed composer from the Composer-Setup.exe (https://getcomposer.org/download/). It changed the php.ini for me for activating some php extensions (openssl, etc).
- I created a project with `composer create-project symfony/skeleton sf4`
- I moved to sf4 dir : `cd C:/sf4`
- I run Web Server : `php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public`
- It works when I browse `locahost:8000`
- So I want to install the symfony twig bundle as a flex package : `composer require twig`

The error I get :

```
 [InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find package twig.

  Did you mean one of these?
      twig/twig
      slim/twig-view
      latte/latte
      twig/extensions
      timber/timber
```

I tried with a local composer.phar inside the sf4 project :

```
cd C:/sf4
php composer.phar require twig
```

=> same error

Composer seems to ignore flex plugin, do you have any idea ? Thx !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the answer of [nicolas-grekas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/322029/nicolas-grekas) in the following [link](https://github.com/symfony/flex/issues/306)

you can continue using the symfony containers in [this link](https://symfony.sh/), just look for the alias that flex used.

in your case twig for flex is "symfony / twig-bundle", run `composer req symfony / twig-bundle`.

salu2

Comment: Please link to the SO user profile when tagging a user. Also use hyperlinks for external URL instead of copy pasting the URL. Please read the SO guidelines before posting.

Comment: Error no longer occurs, I guess it was the composer flex bug you pointed it out. Thank you.